# Standard way of adding JSLT 1.2.1 in a Maven Project?

Tags: maven, jstl, maven-3

What is the standard pom for adding the ***1.2.1*** JSTL taglib in a maven project. Any recommendations as to when/if can this be scoped as `provided` ? Any server peculiarities (interested in Jboss 7, Glassfish 4 and/or Tomcat 7)

**EDIT**: Added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This adds:

[image]

Notice it transitively adds the 1.2 api.

I am using `provided` as I am using Jboss which should provide it: [Basic question complicated solution - Tomcat to JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562890/basic-question-complicated-solution-tomcat-to-jboss/7563616#7563616). Still this is the 1.2 api apparently

```
$ find . -name *jstl*.jar
./modules/javax/servlet/jstl/api/main/jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar
```

(contains implementation also). So would the correct way be to add the jstl jars to the pom (not in provided scope) and mark the servlet-api (I'm on 3 anyway) as provided somehow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up using :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Add the jstl-api dependency explicitly - otherwise jstl-api 1.2 is added -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
         <!-- jstl-api was adding selvlet-api 2.5 and jsp-api-->
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Not sure if I should add the jstl-api dependency - please comment (I would accept a more authoritative answer actually). Result:

[image]

See:

- [Autocomplete with JSP, JSTL 1.2.1 and Servlet 3.0 in Tomcat 7 with Eclipse Kepler](http://frankruenagel.blogspot.gr/2013/09/autocomplete-with-eclipse-kepler-jstl.html)
- [Fix maven JSTL 1.2.1 dependency so maven-war-plugin doesn't package JARs that offend Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288896/fix-maven-jstl-1-2-1-dependency-so-maven-war-plugin-doesnt-package-jars-that-of/13428228#13428228)
- [JBoss 7.1 - Migration to JSF 2.2](https://community.jboss.org/thread/203257) - includes how to upgrate your jstl to 1.2.1

For 1.2:

- [Running JSTL 1.2 on Tomcat 7 using Maven](http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved in Eclipse IDE:
I change Java 11 to Java 8.

1. Right click in Root projet->properties->Project Facets-> mark as checked Java and change to java version 8
2. Go to -> Window-> Preferences->Java->Compiler Here change to Java
   8
3. Go to -> Window-> Preferences->Java->Installed JREs-> Add...Put jre that installed in you OS, in my case is
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).